# In react bootstrap how do I show the contents of an array in an html table

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-bootstrap

I have an array that I add to, each time a button is pressed.  That part appears to work.  When I output it to a console, I can see that each one is getting added.

```
  const addToPool = () => {
    diePool[poolCount] = (
      <die
        type={diceType}
        number={diceNumber}
        adjuster={diceAdjuster}
      />
    );
    poolCount++;
  };
```

How do I loop through and display that in my html table after my form?

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Form>
            <Button onClick={addToPool} aria-controls="diceRoll" aria-expanded={open} variant="secondary" size="sm">
              Add to Pool
            </Button>
          </ButtonToolbar>

        </Form>
        <Fade in={open}>
          <div id="diceRoll">
            The result is: {randNum}
          </div>
        </Fade>
      </header>
      <Table responsive>
      <caption>Dice Pool</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Number</th>
          <th>Adjuster</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </Table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your body tag, you can iterate through an array using the `map` method (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map)

```
<tbody>
  {dice.map((item,index) => { 
    return(
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{item.key1}</td>
      etc...
      </tr>
   )})}
</tbody>
```

Comment: I tried what you posted, and it said "dice is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

In order for React to update the user interface to reflect changes, it expects you to notify it that a change has been made. You do this my modifying the *state* of your component. In your `addToPool` method, you are modifying a local variable called `diePool`. That's just a member variable of the control object, not the state, and React won't know you've made a change.

Instead, modify the state with something like this:

```
const addToPool(diceType, diceNumber, diceAdjuster) {
  this.setState(prevstate => { 
    return {
      diePool: prevstate.diePool.push(
        { type: diceType, number: diceNumber, adjuster: diceAdjuster }
      )
    } 
  });
}
```

For this to work, your component will have to have an initial state to work with. You create this in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  this.state = { diePool: [] };
}
```

Now, whenever your code calls `addToPool`, the state will be updated and through `setState`, React will know about it and call the `render` method as needed.

In your `render` method, you will need to consult the state to place the dice rolls in your table. You can do so by using `map` over your array of dice rolls:

```
<Table responsive>
  // ...snip...
  <tbody>
    {this.state.diePool.map((roll, index) => {
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{roll.type}</td>
        <td>{roll.number}</td>
        <td>{roll.adjuster}</td>
      </tr>
    })}
  </tbody>
</Table>
```

(Please note the use of `index` here to make sure that each table row has a unique index - this is a requirement for React to be able to update table rows individually when it can.)

What's important here is that the component *state* is a crucial concept in React. If you modify something and you expect React to react (ha!) to it, you'll have to modify the state through `setState` (not by modifying `this.state` directly). That's the only way React will know about it. React will then work its magic and call the render methods of your component and its children, as necessary.

Comment: I'm not using any setState, I'm using useState, I also don't have a constructor.  That was part of my issue with the samples I've found, they've all been a little different and haven't worked.

Comment: This answer led me on the right track and its a good explanation, however it didn't fit into my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and posting it here in case others have trouble:

declared a counter:

```
const [poolCount, setPoolCount] = useState(0);
```

Created my addToPool:

```
  const addToPool = () => {
    setDiePool([
      ...diePool,
      {
        dp1 : poolCount,
        dp2 : diceType,
        dp3 : diceNumber,
        dp4 : diceAdjuster
      }
    ]);

    setPoolCount(poolCount+1);
  };
```

Call my addToPool when I click the button:

```
    <Button onClick={addToPool} aria-controls="diceRoll" aria-expanded={open} variant="secondary" size="sm">
    Add to Pool
    </Button>
```

Then create my table and loop:

```
    <Table responsive>
      <caption>Dice Pool</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Number</th>
          <th>Adjuster</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         {diePool.map(die => (<tr key={die.dp1}><td>{die.dp1}</td><td>{die.dp2}</td><td>{die.dp3}</td><td>{die.dp4}</td></tr>))}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
```